# #define macro to define a constant Mat in opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Les say I have a size(3,1) Mat in opencv with precomputed values(different element values), I want to use it with in a function as a constant by first defining it using a #define macro in a header file. Because It is going to be in a function which is going to be called many time. I don't want to initialise the matrix for each calls. is it possible to define a matrix as a global as a constant in #define macro ? how ?

Comment: ... Why not just use a global variable?

Comment: Why not use [Matx](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matx)?  They are designed for small statically sized matrices.  Then it won't be dynamically allocating any memory which should be faster.  What exactly do you need to do with this matrix?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know you can not share the same object between multiple occurances of macro (as macros are resolved by preprocessor which basically copies the piece of code defined by macro to place of macro invocation), so I think you should stick with functions or static methods.

You can define function (or static method) with static Mat object (initialized with your values) which returns reference to the said Mat object. The initialisation can be carried out by lambda funcition. See following example:

```
const cv::Mat &getCustomConstMat()
{
    static cv::Mat customMat(
                []()
                ->cv::Mat
    {
        cv::Mat myMat(3,3, CV_8UC1);
        myMat.at<uchar>(0,0) = static_cast<uchar>(1);
        // here comes the rest of the initialisation
        return cv::Mat(myMat);
    }()
    );
    return customMat;
}
```

In this example, the static object `customMat` is initialized only once (on first call of the function `getCustomConstMat`). It is initialized from return value of lambda function, which creates the desired object, initializes it and returns. This lambda function is executed only once - during the initialisation of static `customMat` object.